# Notification of memory shortage in Java

Tags: java, memory, listener, threshold

Is there any delivered feature in Java notifying a memory shortage in an application (or notifying that it has reach a predefined level)?

I was wondering whether it was possible to register a listener (or something equivalent) somewhere? I know about the memory methods in the Runtime class. I could create a scheduled task checking remaining memory myself, but I am wondering whether there is already an existing solution.

I don't think so, but I am looking for a confirmation.

**FOR THE RECORDS**

```
MemoryMXBean mbean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
NotificationEmitter emitter = (NotificationEmitter) mbean;
NotificationListener listener = new NotificationListener() {

    @Override
    public void handleNotification(Notification notif, Object handback) {

        String notifType = notif.getType();
        if (notifType.equals(MemoryNotificationInfo.MEMORY_THRESHOLD_EXCEEDED) ||
            notifType.equals(MemoryNotificationInfo.MEMORY_COLLECTION_THRESHOLD_EXCEEDED)) {

            // Retrieve the memory notification information
            CompositeData cd = (CompositeData) notif.getUserData();
            MemoryNotificationInfo info = MemoryNotificationInfo.from(cd);
            MemoryUsage mu = info.getUsage();

            System.out.println("Maximum memory = " + mu.getMax());
            System.out.println("Used memory    = " + mu.getUsed());

        }
    }

};

emitter.addNotificationListener(listener, null, null);
```

Comment: @Andy That's what I go from reading through the Javadoc. Not fully tested, but the idea is there....

Comment: Please note that this code will notify you when the memory usage threshold is exceeded... but **you still have to set the threshold value**. This has to be done for each existing memory pool.

Comment: Also, next time you find a possible solution for your problem, please post it as an answer instead of including the solution code in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can set up a listener for a memory usage threshold using the [MemoryMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html). Sample code is provided in the javadoc link.

Comment: +1  I was going to suggest a `try`/`catch` on an `OutOfMemoryError` with some safety measures thrown in, but people always grumble at me for even mentioning the 'heresy' of catching an `Error`.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew I was thinking about suggesting the same thing, but then I saw the answer from @Andy. +1 for this answer.

Comment: @Andrew, It is possible to catch `OutofMemoryError` (and I have done it before), but handling the `Error` well without interrupting the flow of the program is pretty difficult.

Comment: @notnoop:  My strategy involves popping a `JOptionPane` after a large `byte[]` has been `null`ed, so it **definitely** 'interrupts the flow of the program' in terms of user input!

Comment: I am glad I have asked this question, I was nearly going to reinvent the wheel, lol !

Comment: You might also want to capture a heap dump when an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown. On Hotspot, the `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` switch does it. The dump can be imported into VisualVM and will help you in analyzing the problem later. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gdyrr